# Unable to remove last appended element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the `append()` method to append data, and I used `remove()` to remove each element. But, I am unable to remove the last element in the list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add_cart").click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).val("Item Already in Cart");
        $.get("cart.php", {
            "id": id
        }, function (data) {
            $("#sam").append("<table class='tables'><tr><td>" + data + "</td><td><input class='remove' id='" + id + "' type='button' value='Remove'></td></tr></table>");
        });
        $(".tables").click(function () {
            $(this).remove()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: where is `remove()` part?

Comment: Maybe you could use `$(this).html('');` which replaces the content of your table.

Comment: now i edited the remove part

Comment: Even $(this).html(''); is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/).

I assume that, you wan to delete last element when you click `.tables` element,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add_cart").click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).val("Item Already in Cart");
            $("#sam").append("<table class='tables'><tr><td>dasdasdas</td><td><input class='remove' id='3' type='button' value='Remove1'></td></tr><tr><td>dasdasdas</td><td><input class='remove' id='4' type='button' value='Remove4'></td></tr><tr><td>dasdasdas</td><td><input class='remove' id='5' type='button' value='Remove5'></td></tr></table>");
            $(".tables").click(function () {
                $(".tables tr:last-child").remove()
            });
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/8c9NZ/**

If you want to remove each clicked element, you can use;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add_cart").click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).val("Item Already in Cart");
            $("#sam").append("<table class='tables'><tr><td>dasdasdas</td><td><input class='remove' id='3' type='button' value='Remove1'></td></tr><tr><td>dasdasdas</td><td><input class='remove' id='4' type='button' value='Remove4'></td></tr><tr><td>dasdasdas</td><td><input class='remove' id='5' type='button' value='Remove5'></td></tr></table>");
            $(".remove").click(function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove()
            });
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/xyQtU/1/**

Comment: No i dnt want to delete the last element alone.. I want to delete each table when i click on it.. But the last table is not getting deleted...

Comment: In both cases, I provided you the code and working examples. So have you tried my code and made it worked? If yes, an upvote will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To remove last element from the list use this:

```
$(selectAllListElements).last().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
 $(".tables").click(function () {
            $(this).remove()
        });
```

with:

```
   $(".tables").on('click' , function () {
        $(this).remove()
    });
```